# Karma+Jasmine test for a Angular SPA fail randomly in AfterAll

Tags: angular, karma-jasmine

We are building a Angular single page application. Some commit in the last weeks made random test failures appear in the AfterAll-method, with the following error message:

```
AfterAll Uncaught TypeError: You provided 'undefined' where a stream was expected. You can provide an Observable, Promise, Array, or Iterable. thrown
```

The error sometimes does not appear; there is no error in any of the specs when checking out the Karma console in the browser except for this one. I am having a hard time finding the source of the error; I am not sure how to get a proper stacktrace for it. We didn't define any AfterAll (it must be some default spec run by Karma). Disabling or Enabling random test order does not affect the random failure.

Our used versions are as follows:

```
"karma": "^4.0.1",
"karma-chrome-launcher": "~2.2.0",
"karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "^1.2.1",
"karma-jasmine": "~2.0.1",
"karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^1.4.2",
"karma-junit-reporter": "^1.2.0"
```

How can I get a proper stacktrace for this error? What could be going wrong randomly?

Comment: We need some code so we can understand better what the problem may be and help you better. If possible [edit] the post and add the code inside the `AfterAll` method and anything else related to it.

Comment: I know this has already been answered but I just encountered this same problem, and it appears this blog article is highly relevant: https://blog.pragmatists.com/flaky-test-in-angular-lesson-learned-3e094894913f

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to find the faulty test by isolation one module after another. It looks like this:

```
import { HttpClientTestingModule } from '@angular/common/http/testing';
import { Component, Input } from '@angular/core';
import { async, ComponentFixture, TestBed } from '@angular/core/testing';
import { RouterTestingModule } from '@angular/router/testing';
import { DxBoxModule, DxListModule, DxToolbarModule } from 'devextreme-angular';
import { NGXLogger, NGXLoggerMock } from 'ngx-logger';
import { of } from 'rxjs';
import { CalendarDataStoreService } from '../../services/calendar-data-store.service';
import { ExampleCommunicationService } from '../../services/example-communication.service';
import { ExamplePageComponent } from './example-page.component';

@Component({selector: 'example-calendar-list', template: ''})
class ExampleCalendarListStubComponent {
  @Input() dataSource;
  @Input() selectedItem;
}

@Component({selector: 'example-toolbar', template: ''})
class ExampleToolbarStubComponent {
  @Input() selectedCalendar;
}

describe('ExamplePageComponent', () => {
  let component: ExamplePageComponent;
  let fixture: ComponentFixture<ExamplePageComponent>;

  beforeEach(async(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      imports: [
        DxBoxModule,
        RouterTestingModule,
        DxListModule,
        DxToolbarModule,
        HttpClientTestingModule
      ],
      declarations: [
        ExamplePageComponent,
        ExampleToolbarStubComponent,
        ExampleCalendarListStubComponent
      ],
      providers: [
        {
          provide: CalendarDataStoreService, useValue: {
            createDataSource: () => {},
            modified$: of(true)
          }
        },
        {provide: ExampleCommunicationService, useValue: {}},
        {provide: NGXLogger, useClass: NGXLoggerMock},
      ]
    })
      .compileComponents();
  }));

  beforeEach(() => {
    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(ExamplePageComponent);
    component = fixture.componentInstance;
    fixture.detectChanges();
  });

  xit('should create', () => {
    expect(component).toBeTruthy();
  });
});
```

The line generating a provider is the problem:

```
{
              provide: CalendarDataStoreService, useValue: {
                createDataSource: () => {},
                modified$: of(true)
              }
```

The DataSource that is being created for the provider causes AfterAll() to fail after the test runs.

Answer (score 4):

Karma since version 3 runs tests in the same `suite` (`describe()` in a random order.

Without seeing the actual tests, it's impossible to figure out which test is causing the problem. But the symptoms you describe suggest that one of your tests mutates some state on a component that your tests rely on. It seems you don't have a `beforeEach()` to reset the main state for every test.

If you can post the tests and components that are causing this, I could help you pinpoint the test that is mutating state and not repairing it. Or you can reach out to me privately if you want.

Comment: The thing is: we have 160 specs, 30 of them are skipped, the others run fine, and then after the testing is finished it still throws the error, so I am not sure how I can find out which test to share/anonymize. Is there any way to find that out?

Comment: Is there any `afterAll()` in your specs at all? Else, I'm afraid this is the trouble of testing and it'll be a time consuming job to fix, perhaps something for a more junior dev ;-). Considering that the combination of tests may be the issue, disabling all and reenabling one by one will probably not lead you to the cause of the issue.

Comment: The more reliable option is to add some logging to the `beforeEach()` or `beforeAll()` statements if you have `afterAll()` methods in your specs. If you however have none of these; it's probably the testing framework itself throwing the error. Have you googled for similar error messages with Karma/Jasmine?

Comment: Else your option is to go back on a local branch to before the commit that broke it all and see what tests were touched in that commit. I'm afraid that if there's a lot of tests touched in there, you'll have to go about them one by one to isolate the issue.

Comment: Yeah, there's no afterAll() in our entire codebase. Is it possible to define what I am actually looking for? Does the afterAll() check something or try to do something by default, which is hindered by a test possibly?

Comment: You could run your karma/jasmine tests in debug mode so you have an open browser with a stacktrace. This might contain a hint to or help isolate what is causing the issue.

Comment: @Bjorn'Bjeaurn'S Is there an option to force tests to run in default order like v2 did?

Answer (score 4):

You can use [fdescribe/xdescribe](https://davidtang.io/2016/01/03/controlling-which-tests-run-in-jasmine.html) to narrow down the spec file that is generating this issue. Then you can get the problematic test by using fit/xit.

P.S: It is not necessary that there is an issue in your spec files. Sometimes, a glitch in your code can cause this type of error. Once you know which test is generating this error, it will become easier to spot the underlying problem.

Comment: Also, keep in mind that the error here is not just caused by a test(s), but the combination run too. I suffered myself this once when upgrading karma/jasmine and it was a bit time consuming finding the actual cause (a state mutation) and I didn't have too many tests in the suite.

Comment: I was able to isolate it; it is actually caused by a single test. I am still in the process of finding out why it causes AfterAll() to fail. I'll post an answer once I find out.

Comment: Glad, I could help. Kindly share the details of CalendarDataStoreService, we may detect the real culprit. Plus, don't forget to mark my answer as accepted.